# Building new Model A form from Model B attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, each, nested-attributes

I'm trying to copy the values from Model A nested attributes to Model B nested attributes. The nested fields are the same in their respective tables. Just the parents are different.

I pass the model A value: `Model_B_new_path(@routine)` and get its value in controller B: `@routine = Routine.find(params[:id])`, but copying the nested attributes is where I'm stuck.

```
class RoutineSetRep

    belongs_to :routine

end


class Routine

    has_many :routine_set_reps, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :routine_set_reps, allow_destroy: true

    validates_associated :routine_set_reps
end

class WorkoutSetRep

    belongs_to: :workout

end

class Workout
    has_many :workout_set_reps, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_set_reps, allow_destroy: true

    validates_associated :workout_set_reps
end
```

Controllers:

```
   Controller Workout /  Controller B
            def new
            @new_routine_workout = Routine.find_by(id: params[:routine_id])
            @routine = @new_routine_workout
            c = @routine.routine_set_reps.count
            @workout = current_user.workouts.new(@routine.attributes.except('public'))
            c.times{ @workout.workout_set_reps.build }
            end
    
        def workout_params
          params.fetch(:workout, {}).permit(:id, :sport_id, :name, :user_id, :routine_id,
          workout_set_reps_attributes: [:id, :set, :rep, :weight, :distance, :workout_id, :exercise_id,
                                :user_id, :weight_unit, :distance_unit, :_destroy],)
                               
        end
end
```

I can make the form build the number of fields that should be populated, but aren't.

Would this be a deep clone problem in which I have to create a method that grabs each routine_set_rep? Something like:

```
    @routine.routine_set_reps.each do |set|
       set.exercise_id = @workout.workout_set_reps.exercise_id 
    end
```

This does not work but seems to be the right direction. With that said is the idea behind it, is that possible?

When I set the build option to build previous workout records it works fine.

```
@past_workout = Workout.find_by(id: params[:past_workout_id])
@workout = current_user.workouts.new(@past_workout.attributes.except('public')).copy_workout
```

The form:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "nested-fields", data: { new_record: form.object.new_record? } do %>
  <div class="form-group">
  <%= form.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:exercise_id, Exercise.order(:tool), :id, :name_with_tool, {prompt: nil}, {class: 'form'}) %>
  <%= form.text_field :set, placeholder: "Set", class: "set-control" %>
  <%= form.text_field :rep, placeholder: "Rep", class: "set-control" %>
  <%= form.text_field :weight, placeholder: "Weight", class: "set-control" %>
  <%= form.collection_select :weight_unit, WorkoutSetRep::WEIGHT, :to_s, :titleize, {prompt: nil}, {:class => 'set-control'} %>
  <%= form.text_field :distance, placeholder: "Distance To Run", class: "set-control" %>
  <small><%= link_to "Remove", "#", class: "btn btn--destroy", data: { action: "click->nested-form#remove_association" } %></small>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've stumbled onto these post for help,[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-duplicate-an-activerecord-record) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983575/ruby-on-rails-clone-dup-with-filtered-nested-elements) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378257/ruby-on-rails-deep-copy-deep-clone-of-object-and-its-attributes) which they have, but I'm still lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I set the variables, then I was able to iterate over them. Is this is the rails way? I don't know but it works and the max number of objects it would iterate over is 20.

```
@routine = Routine.includes(:routine_set_reps).find_by(id: params[:routine_id])
@workout = current_user.workouts.new(@routine.attributes.extract!('name', 'sport'))

c = r.count
r = @routine.routine_set_reps     
 w = @workout.workout_set_reps
        c.times{ w.new }
         r.zip(w).each do |routine, workout|
            workout.exercise_id = routine.exercise_id
            workout.set = routine.set
            workout.rep = routine.rep
            workout.weight = routine.weight
            workout.weight_unit = routine.weight_unit
         end
```

Probably could refactor this into a method and just call it but for now working is working.

Just fyi I use `=` instead of `||=` because the `workout_set_reps` will always be new. Is this right? I'm not positive, but leave a comment if you believe differently or agree with a reason.